# Reword tag wiki excerpts for language-specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

We have quite a few tags for specific languages, e.g. [chinese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese), [english](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english), [japanese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese), [mongolian](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongolian), [spanish](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish), [esperanto](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esperanto), [french](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french), [hebrew](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew), [german](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german), [russian](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian), [korean](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korean), [greek](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek), [arabic](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic),  [aramaic](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aramaic), [thai](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thai), [tagalog](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagalog), [tamazight](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tamazight), [tatar](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tatar), [swahili](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swahili), [latin](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin), [georgian](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georgian) and [danish](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danish). In addition, we also have a few tags for language families.

We regularly get questions about specific features of individual languages, e.g.

- [Why is right spell “eating” not “eatting”?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2562/800) (now deleted)
- ['Leuk-' prefix in greek and its grammatically correct usage](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2556/800)
- [Does the BCS adjective “sinji” (grey-blue) have an associated noun?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2531/800)

People who submit such questions usually also select the correct language-specific tags (or tags for language families), so it is likely that they see the pop-up tag wiki excerpt. But all of our tag wiki excerpts follow this pattern (or something very similar):

> Questions related to [language X], ...

Should we reformulate these tag wiki excerpt using the following pattern to reduce the number of off-topic questions? (Emphasis added:)

> Questions related to **learning or teaching** [language X], ...

Answer (score 3):

"Questions related to learning or teaching ... " is redundant, as all tags are on questions, and all questions on this site are about learning or teaching languages. Describing the purpose and scope of the site in every tag wiki doesn't make sense to me.

I'd much prefer:

[english](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english)

> English is a Germanic language spoken in...

I'm highly skeptical of the claim that changing the tag wikis will reduce this type of off-topic questions. If someone won't bother to familiarize them with the site enough to know that such questions don't belong here, I'm not sure why we'd expect them to read the tag descriptions.

And further, I expect the people asking these questions already think they are about "learning or teaching"... that's why they're here in the first place. So even if they did read the tag description, it wouldn't clarify anything to them.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes. 
Long answer: Yes.

This would help clear up most confusion about the misuse of these language specific tags by beginners.